# Add and Remove Active Class on Click but preventDefault stop the action to the href (html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

## CSS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.menu li a').click(function(e) {

    $('.menu li.active').removeClass('active');

    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

## html

```
<div class="header-left">
    <a href="index.html" class="logo">
        <img src="assets/images/C&M logo.png" alt="Molla Logo"
             width="105" height="25">
    </a>

    <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul class="menu sf-arrows">
            <li class="megamenu-container active">
                <a href="index-2.html" class="sf-with-ul">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="category.html" class="sf-with-ul">Shop</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="blog-listing.html" class="sf-with-ul">Blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- End .menu -->
    </nav><!-- End .main-nav -->

</div><!-- End .header-left -->
```

When run, it is work on add and remove active, but it didn't show the categories.html when click "Shop".

This is how my HTML renders:

[image: Rendered HTML]

Comment: Hi PS.  Just remove `e.preventDefault()`.  You want the default behavior of the link.

Comment: can't work if remove 'e.preventDefault()'. If remove it, active also can't work but href is work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.